# Need fresh eyes on Python assertRegexpMatches

Tags: python, regex, debugging

my Regex that I am using is :

```
ur"^[\s\S]*Ticket Price (including £0.50 booking fees)[\s\S]£5.50[\s\S]*$"
```

and the string I am comparing to is :

```
"Ticket Price (including £0.50 booking fees) £5.50"
```

I have already been messing around with it on regex101.com but to no avail. The logic seems right to me, but they are not matching (I am trying to use assertRegexpMatches() to test code). Any help or tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Escape `(`and `)`.. Otherwise you'll have groups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the **paranthesis** and also the dots (decimal). In regex `(..)` called capturing group used to capture chars. To match literal `(`, `)` brackets, you must escape them in the regex.

```
ur"^[\s\S]*Ticket Price \(including £0\.50 booking fees\)[\s\S]£5\.50[\s\S]*$"
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/cF6gK3/1)

Comment: Thank you Avinash. The dots are supposed accept any character though (I think), why wouldn't they work?

Comment: because dot will match a literal dot.